# Java enums vs constants for Strings

Tags: java, enums

I've switched from using constants for Strings to using enums.  Many times I need the `String` representation of the enum (for logging, to pass to an API that requires a `String`, etc).

With `String` constants, you can just pass the String value, but with enums you have to call `toString()`.  Is there a way you can "default" to the String value when supplying the enum variable?

As many posters have commented, perhaps one shouldn't be using enums if you frequently need the `String` representation.

Comment: Why are you assigning an enum value to a string variable in the fourth code block?

Comment: What is the use case? Why are you doing this?

Comment: Updated the post to hopefully be more articulate!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should fully adopt `enum` and not use the `String` representation in the first place. Only use the `toString()` to generate messages, logs, etc, but internally you'd want to work with `enum`. Any `Map`, `Set`, etc operations should be done on the `enum` type, which guarantees proper serialization, singleton pattern, and everything else that `enum` types are supposed to have.

In your snippet:

```
 Object o = map.get(Options.OPTION_1);
 //This won't work as intended if the Map key is a String
```

Compile-time error aside, you should really question whether the map key should even be of type `String` in the first place. The way you're using it, it looks like it should be a `Map<Options, Something>`.

Answer (score 9):

There are a lot of good reasons to use `Enum` in Java.  But not if you only need a `String`.

For example, if you are representing a specific set of entities and don't want them to be type-equivalent with other kinds of things (like `String`s), then an `Enum` would be appropriate.  Moreso if you are going to be calling functions that operate them and differentiate based on the particular instance.

On the other hand, if you are only interested in the `String` value of something, then there is nothing wrong with a `String` constant.

From what you've posted, I can't tell what the use case is.  Is there some reason you need to use `Enum` here?